# How to sum of two different table with two different groupby

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables called `work` and `stuff` both tables have same fields -
 `company`, `quality`, `quantity`

I need the sum of all the `quantity` of work with group by `company` and `quality` and join the table with sum of all the `quantity` of stuff with group by `company` and `quality`

I didn't get the expected result.
SQLfiddel 
 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eea577/6

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or, even worse, links to images.)

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Please, not as a comment, edit the question instead,

Comment: i am new for stackoverflow

Comment: Small though these tables are I am unwilling to retype them. If you could add them as text to the question or to sqlfiddle I would be happy to look again.

Comment: please any one solve my query i have attached the query in Sql fiddle

Answer (score 1):

working query

```
select st.company,st.quality,st.quantitys - ct.quantitys as balance from
(select company,quality,sum(quantity) as quantitys from stuff
 group by quality,company) as st join (select company,quality,
 sum(quantity) as quantitys from work group by quality,company)
 as ct on `ct`.`company` = `st`.`company` and ct.quality = st.quality group by quality,company
```

u have missed the quality condition in the join

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT tableA.ID, tableA.`Year`, tableA.`Month`,  
       tableA.`Type`, tableA.instrument, 
       tableA.totalAmount, tableB.totalInstrument
FROM
(
    SELECT  a.ID, a.`Year`, a.`Month`, 
            b.`Type`, b.instrument, 
            SUM(b.`amount`) totalAmount
    FROM    `date` a
                INNER JOIN `transactions` b
                    ON a.ID = b.id
    GROUP BY b.`Type
) tableA
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT  a.ID, a.`Year`, a.`Month`, 
            b.`Type`, b.instrument, 
            SUM(b.`instrument`) totalInstrument
    FROM    `date` a
                INNER JOIN `transactions` b
                    ON a.ID = b.id
    GROUP BY a.`Year`, a.`Month`
) tableB ON tableA.ID = tableB.ID AND
            tableA.`Year` = tableB.`Year` AND
            tableA.`Month` = tableB.`Month`
```

Comment: hey guys i got solution for the problem . Problem is i am i don't add the quality condition in join query thanks for the response ! working fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c080da/1